# Import Android studio project as module

Tags: android, gradle, import, module

[image: My Image]

I want to import a android studio project into another android studio project. so i have imported it as module in the android studio project. this message project already have module that are used in the project. i have imported message project in android studio successfully. but when i adding a dependency it is not showing this module, so please check image that i have imported and how can i add dependency of message module.

I have tried

```
implementation project(':message')
```

But getting a error

```
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :message. Show Details Affected Modules: app

ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :message.

Show Details Affected Modules: app

ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :message. Show Details Affected Modules: app
```

Comment: Is *message* a **library module** or **application module**?

Comment: message is a android studio project and vcard and photoviewer are the module of message project. now i want to import message android studio project to another android studio project as a module.

Comment: You'll need to convert it to library module before you use it in your :app module.

Comment: how can i convert it to library

Answer (score 3):

You should have a structure like this:

```
   -rootApp
    |--build.gradle
    |--settings.gradle
    |--app
    |----build.gradle

    -rootMessage
    |--build.gradle
    |--settings.gradle
    |--vcard
    |----build.gradle
```

Inside a project you can refer an external module.

Just use:

In `rootApp/settings.gradle`:

```
include ':app' 
include ':myExternalLib'
project(':myExternalLib').projectDir=new   File('/path-to-project/rootMessage/vcard')
```

In `app/build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':myExternalLib')
}
```

Pay attention to myExternalLib.
**You have to use the path of the library inside the other project, not the root of the project.**
In your case the path is  `rootMessage/vcard`.
Also,the `rootMessage/settings.gradle` will not be read because you are using the rootApp project.

Comment: I have a problem. In this message is a a project and vcard is the module of this project and now i want to import message as well as its module in the new project. i have tried this and convert message into library now getting a android manifest merger error.

Comment: @PuneetKansal Read the answer. It explains that you can use a module/library of another project, but you can't import a entire project (the root folder). You can import vcard and the other modules at the same level, but you can't import the whole message project.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added this module name in `setting.gradle`

Like:

**First thing**

```
include ':app', ':message', ':photoviewer', 'vcard'
```

**second thing**

The major issue is that there you applied plugin is **com.android.application** instead of **com.android.library**.

**`apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`**

Write down the below line.

**`apply plugin: 'com.android.library'`**

Comment: yes i have added this, message is a android studio project and i want to import this project in the another project as a module. and photoviewer are the module of message project.

Comment: mean, you want to make this as the flavour of android app.

Comment: no i found a solution will try to implement. may be i have to convert this project to library before import.